# Welcome messages to encourage new users

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/auto-response-to-font-identification-questions) about font identification, asked recently by Brendan, Aarthi mentioned [this post in the Mi Yodeya site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users).

It basically invites the site's usuals to welcome new users by following a series of patterns that include leaving messages to encourage participation:

> Here's the pattern I usually follow:
>
> I wait until I see a question or answer from a new user that I think
>   is on-topic and at all valuable. (If I'm not sure if the user is new,
>   I click into the user profile and see if there are any prior valuable
>   questions or answers.)
>
> If the content is upvote-worthy, I upvote the question or answer.
>
> I leave a comment on it starting with something like:
>
> @user, Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the [positive
>   adjective] question/answer! If the question or answer could use some
>   improvement (e.g. adding a source), I add guidance to that effect.
>
> If the new user is unregistered (which will apparent from the word
>   "Unregistered" near the top of the user's /users/[number] page), I add
>   something like:
>
> Please consider
>   [registering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your
>   account, which will [give you
>   access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)
>   to more of the site's features.

**Do you think we should do something similar here, "rewarding" new users for good questions**, and of course also warning them if (as it happens a lot with the [font-identification] tag) they are missing the point of the site?

The 'corrective' comment happens naturally most of the time, but **do you think we should agree on a welcome text too, and encourage it as a community?**

**EDIT:** If we agree on this idea, we could remove the spider webs and sweep the floor of that poor chat room we have, and decide on the messages there (Welcome message, font identification boilerplate, and any other ideas).

Comment: Yes, and part of the answer should probably be some agreement on what we call ourselves, what we're welcoming them to... I often just go with "...the site", "GD.SE" is the next best but I imagine it's a bit of a "Huh? What's GD.SE?" for most people.

Comment: ...speaking of, if [we're going to get promoted and leave beta](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/404/plan-for-graphic-design-design-and-promotion), do we get a 'proper' name like "Graphic Answers" or something? If so any news on what it's going to be or how it's going to be decided on? (maybe that should be a seperate question)

Comment: @user568458 I think it would make a good new question (easier to see opinions in the shape an answers, rather than comments).

Comment: Possible inspiration: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Very good idea. Can we have something like [Text building blocks](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/430)?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Definitely. I'll add some in a new question, if there isn't a set being used at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Tochecz shared a link to a [similar discussion in TeX.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) that is worth taking a look at. they mention that most of the new visitors are people who's more used to forums, so based on that I used the first paragraph from them for a possible welcome text.

If agreed we put it as a new question and use it as an introduction. An adapted copy of [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Feel free to edit.

---

Welcome to Graphic Design, the free, community driven Questions and Answers site for 2D design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.

Here is some information to help you get started:

- This site is for Questions and answers and is not a forum. This means that there is a quite strict format enforced here. Please post an answerable question using the Ask Question button (after searching for existing similar questions first of course) or post an solution for an existing question as an answer post.
- Once you have enough reputation you can comment other people's posts. Please do not start long discussions in the questions. Use the [chat](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) instead.
- Questions and answers can receive positive and negative votes to indicate their quality. Answers are sorted after the number of votes, and their numbers increase or decrease the reputation of the author of the post.
- It is highly recommended to add an image that illustrates your problem. This makes it easier for others to visually understand it. If you don't have enough reputation to insert it, add the link and someone else will add it for you.
- Please avoid opening and closing lines like "Hi" (already automatically removed) and "Thanks". It makes questions easier to read, so will assume the greeting and gratitude :). Use the first paragraph for a short overview: This is the part that also appears in the Home.
- Please write in English, it doesn't have to be perfect, but posts should show some basic effort. This will make your post readable to most people and greatly improves the chance of getting good answers. The fact that all posts are editable also means that other users may correct your English for you if necessary.
- While you can post questions and answers as unregistered user, please consider registering your account. Otherwise you might create a new, different unregistered account with the same name and icon. Then you will not be able to edit your old posts or add comments to them. You can ask a moderator to merge such accounts together.
- Questions about the site itself should be asked on [Meta.Graphicdesign](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), not on the main site.